# how to add version control using base route mappings in AWS API Gateway?

Tags: aws-api-gateway

I'm adding an API to my custom domain and I want to version it, for example

```
api.test.com/v1/{proxy+},
```

My api is REST and I tried within it and it only works this way //v1/{proxy+}
I tried Configure Api mappings in Path but it doesn't work.